# Sorting a multi-dimensional array with date in PHP

Tags: php

I have a multi-dimensional array that consists of a date value (second field).
I am trying to sort the entire array with descending order of dates using the below logic:

```
$cars = array
  (
    array("Volvo","09/09/2016 10:39:50 am",18),
    array("BMW","09/09/2016 10:38:46 am",13),
    array("Saab","09/09/2017 10:38:49 am",200),
    array("Saab","09/09/2016 10:38:49 am",2),

    );


    echo $cars[0][0]."   ".$cars[0][1]."    ".$cars[0][2];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $cars[1][0]."   ".$cars[1][1]."    ".$cars[1][2];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $cars[2][0]."   ".$cars[2][1]."    ".$cars[2][2];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $cars[3][0]."   ".$cars[3][1]."    ".$cars[3][2];
    echo "<br>";  


  usort($cars, "cmp");

  function cmp($a, $b){ 
      return strcmp($b[1], $a[1]); 
  }
  echo "<br>";
    echo $cars[0][0]."   ".$cars[0][1]."    ".$cars[0][2];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $cars[1][0]."   ".$cars[1][1]."    ".$cars[1][2];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $cars[2][0]."   ".$cars[2][1]."    ".$cars[2][2];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $cars[3][0]."   ".$cars[3][1]."    ".$cars[3][2];
     echo "<br>";
```

However the above is giving me the below output :

Before :----------

Volvo 09/09/2016 10:39:50 am 18

BMW 09/09/2016 10:38:46 am 13

Saab 09/09/2010 10:38:49 am 200

Saab 09/08/2016 10:38:49 am 2

After :----------

Volvo 09/09/2016 10:39:50 am 18

BMW 09/09/2016 10:38:46 am 13

Saab 09/09/2010 10:38:49 am 200

Saab 09/08/2016 10:38:49 am 2

the output I am expecting is :

Volvo 09/09/2016 10:39:50 am 18

BMW 09/09/2016 10:38:46 am 13

Saab 09/08/2016 10:38:49 am 2

Saab 09/09/2010 10:38:49 am 200

Any help will be highly useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `usort()` and `strtotime()` to compare dates

```
usort($cars, function($a, $b){
    return strtotime($a[1]) < strtotime($b[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7

```
usort($cars, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a[1]) <=> strtotime($b[1]);
});
```